# Водяной знак и видео

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift4, watermark

Как мне добавить водяной знак (текст и лого) в снятое видео используя Swift. Я видил несколько вопросов как добавить водяной знак в изображение, люди в ответах вставляют кастомные классы...ничего больше. Не могу понять как это сделать для видео, стоит ли и как использовать кастомные классы. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Используйте [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage).

Можно добавить в видео обычные UILabel и UIImageView.

---

UPD: Пример кода:

Файл Podfile:

```
pod 'GPUImage'
```

Файл Info.plist:

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>I need</string>
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>I need</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>I need</string>
```

Файл videoRecordVC.swift (надо добавить кнопку btnRecord в любое место и картинку mycat.png или любую другую):

```
import UIKit
import GPUImage
import Photos

class videoRecordVC: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var btnRecord: UIButton!

var filterView: GPUImageView!
var videoCamera: GPUImageVideoCamera!
var uiElement: GPUImageUIElement!
var filter: GPUImageBrightnessFilter!
var blendFilter: GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter!
var uiElementInput: GPUImageUIElement!

var catImageView: UIImageView!

var movieWriter: GPUImageMovieWriter?
var isRecording = false

var fileURL: URL?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    filterView = GPUImageView(frame: self.view.bounds)
    self.view.addSubview(filterView)
    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(btnRecord)

    videoCamera = GPUImageVideoCamera(
        sessionPreset: AVCaptureSession.Preset.vga640x480.rawValue,
        cameraPosition: AVCaptureDevice.Position.back)
    videoCamera.outputImageOrientation = .portrait
    videoCamera.horizontallyMirrorFrontFacingCamera = false
    videoCamera.horizontallyMirrorRearFacingCamera = false

    filter = GPUImageBrightnessFilter()
    blendFilter = GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter()
    blendFilter.mix = 1.0

    videoCamera.addTarget(filter)

    let contentView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 640, height: 480))
    self.catImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "mycat")!)
    contentView.addSubview(catImageView)

    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 200, width: 300, height: 50))
    label.text = "Black cat"
    label.font = UIFont(name: label.font.fontName, size: 30)
    contentView.addSubview(label)

    uiElementInput = GPUImageUIElement(view: contentView)

    filter.addTarget(blendFilter)
    uiElementInput.addTarget(blendFilter)
    blendFilter.addTarget(filterView)

    filter.frameProcessingCompletionBlock = { filter, time in
        self.uiElementInput.update()
    }

    videoCamera.startCapture()

}

@IBAction func actRecord(_ sender: Any) {

    if (!isRecording) {
        do {
            self.isRecording = true
            let documentsDir = try FileManager.default.url(for:.documentDirectory, in:.userDomainMask, appropriateFor:nil, create:true)
            fileURL = URL(string:"test.mp4", relativeTo:documentsDir)!
            do {
                try FileManager.default.removeItem(at:fileURL!)
            } catch {
            }

            movieWriter = GPUImageMovieWriter(movieURL: fileURL!, size: CGSize(width: 480, height: 800))
            movieWriter?.shouldPassthroughAudio = true
            blendFilter.addTarget(movieWriter)
            movieWriter?.startRecording()

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                (sender as! UIButton).titleLabel!.text = "Stop"
            }
        } catch {
            fatalError("Couldn't initialize movie, error: \(error)")
        }
    } else {
        movieWriter?.finishRecording {
            self.isRecording = false

            PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
                PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: self.fileURL!)
            }) { saved, error in
                if saved {
                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Your video was successfully saved", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
                    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
                    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
                    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
                print("error: \(error)")
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                (sender as! UIButton).titleLabel!.text = "Record"
            }
            self.movieWriter = nil
        }
    }

}


}
```

В файле videoProcessingVC.swift пример добавления UILabel и UIImageView в уже существующее видео:

```
import UIKit
import GPUImage
import Photos

class videoProcessingVC: UIViewController {

var imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
var videoURL: URL?
var fileURL: URL?

var movieFile: GPUImageMovie!

var movieWriter: GPUImageMovieWriter?
var isRecording = false

var filterView: GPUImageView!
var uiElement: GPUImageUIElement!
var filter: GPUImageBrightnessFilter!
var blendFilter: GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter!
var uiElementInput: GPUImageUIElement!

var catImageView: UIImageView!


@IBOutlet weak var btnProcessing: UIButton!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    filterView = GPUImageView(frame: self.view.bounds)
    self.view.addSubview(filterView)
    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(btnProcessing)

}

@IBAction func actProcessing(_ sender: Any) {

    imagePickerController.sourceType = .savedPhotosAlbum
    imagePickerController.delegate = self
    imagePickerController.mediaTypes = ["public.movie"]
    present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func doProcessing() {

    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true

    do {
        let documentsDir = try FileManager.default.url(for:.documentDirectory, in:.userDomainMask, appropriateFor:nil, create:true)
        fileURL = URL(string:"test3.mov", relativeTo:documentsDir)!
        try FileManager.default.removeItem(at:fileURL!)
    } catch {
    }

    movieFile = GPUImageMovie.init(url: videoURL)
    movieFile.runBenchmark = false
    movieFile.playAtActualSpeed = false

    filter = GPUImageBrightnessFilter()
    filterView.setInputRotation(kGPUImageRotateRight, at: 90)
    filter.addTarget(filterView)
    movieFile.addTarget(filter)

    let contentView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 640, height: 480))
    self.catImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "mycat")!)
    contentView.addSubview(catImageView)

    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 200, width: 300, height: 50))
    label.text = "Black cat"
    label.font = UIFont(name: label.font.fontName, size: 30)
    contentView.addSubview(label)

    uiElementInput = GPUImageUIElement(view: contentView)

    blendFilter = GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter()
    blendFilter.mix = 1.0

    filter.addTarget(blendFilter)
    uiElementInput.addTarget(blendFilter)

    filter.frameProcessingCompletionBlock = { filter, time in
        self.uiElementInput.update()
    }

    let asset: AVURLAsset = AVURLAsset(url: videoURL!)
    let videoAssetTrack: AVAssetTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video)[0]

    print("fileURL: \(fileURL)")
    movieWriter = GPUImageMovieWriter(movieURL: fileURL!, size: CGSize(width: videoAssetTrack.naturalSize.height, height: videoAssetTrack.naturalSize.width))
    movieWriter?.shouldPassthroughAudio = true
    movieWriter?.setInputRotation(kGPUImageRotateRight, at: 90)
    blendFilter.setInputRotation(kGPUImageRotateLeft, at: 90)
    blendFilter.addTarget(movieWriter)

    movieFile.audioEncodingTarget = movieWriter
    movieFile.enableSynchronizedEncoding(using: movieWriter)

    movieWriter?.startRecording()
    movieFile.startProcessing()

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5, execute: {
        print("End 1")
        self.movieWriter?.finishRecording {
            print("End 2")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.movieFile.endProcessing()

                PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
                    PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: self.fileURL!)
                }) { saved, error in
                    print("End 3")
                    if saved {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Your video was successfully saved", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
                            let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
                            alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
                            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                            UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
                        }
                    }
                    print("error PHPhotoLibrary: \(error) - \(self.fileURL!)")
                }
            }
        }
    })

}

}

extension videoProcessingVC: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

public func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    videoURL = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL] as? URL
    print("videoURL:\(String(describing: videoURL))")
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    doProcessing()
}

}
```

[Репозиторий с примером](https://github.com/nightsilf/GPUImageWithLabel)

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ! Как мне это сделать? Мне надо лейбл и аймедж добавить видео, лейбл - это никнейм и дата, а в аймедже - лого.

Comment: @TravisLertov На swift я не напишу, есть работающий пример на Objective C: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41295653/add-dynamic-text-gpuimage-to-filtered-video. Можете переписать его на swift.

Comment: @TravisLertov Только что заметил, что вышла вторая версия GPUImage2 https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage2, уже на swift. Готового примера под нее нет, но можно поэксперементировать с вот этим: https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage2/tree/master/examples/iOS/SimpleVideoRecorder

Comment: что-то вообще с этим не получается, запустил пример GPUImage2 - вообще в примере нет никакого добавление водяного знака - только можно снять видео и все...может есть еще какие-то способы?

Comment: @TravisLertov Добавил в ответ работающий пример.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, возможно как-то добавлять водяной знак к уже знятому видео. Допустим юзер уже снял видео с помощью AVKit, тоисть мне надо добавить знак к уже знятому видео по нажатию кнопки...

Comment: @TravisLertov Добавил пример добавления в существующее видео.

Comment: Спасибо большое вам за ответ, еще такой вопросик, можно дописать коментарии что и как работает. Потому что работаю с этим первый раз - и что-то вообще не въезжаю

Comment: @TravisLertov Там совершенно очевидный и легко читаемый алгоритм, который можно брать за основу. Если есть конкретные вопросы - я постараюсь ответить.